# Adding variable name to column in for statement

Tags: r, for-loop, variables

I have multiple columns in a table called "Gr1","Gr2",...,"Gr10".

I want to convert the class from character to integer. I want to do it in a dynamic way, I'm trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  Col <- paste0('Students1$Gr',i)
  Col <- as.integer(Col)
                 }
```

My objective here is to know how to add dynamically the *for variable* to the name of a column. Something like:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  Students1$Gr(i) <- as.integer(Students1$Gr(i))
                }
```

Any idea is welcome.
Thank you very much,
Matias

Comment: You want to change a table/matrix from `character` to `integer`? is it this what you want? your question is not so clear to me.

Comment: The best "R" way to do this would be with an `*apply`. Something like: `cols <- names(Students)[grepl("Gr", names(Students))];
Students[, cols] <- lapply(Students[,cols], as.integer)`

Comment: @MikeH.`sapply` might be better than `lapply` since we are not working with lists here.

Comment: @phil_t I believe we are working with lists. `data.frame`s are lists with a few additional properties (see `is.list(data.frame(a=1))`). We are trying to replace list elements (the numeric vectors) with other elements (character vectors). `sapply` would work because it'll return a matrix, but then that has to be put back into list elements when you assign it to the `data.frame`. Also I dislike `sapply` because it simplifies the result for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Example matrix
xm <- matrix(as.character(1:100), ncol = 10);
colnames(xm) <- paste0('Gr', 1:10);

# Example data frame
xd <- as.data.frame(xm, stringsAsFactors = FALSE);

# For matrices, this works
xm <- apply(X = xm, MARGIN = 2, FUN = as.integer);

# For data frames, this works
for (i in 1:10) {
    xd[ , paste0('Gr', i)] <- as.integer(xd[ , paste0('Gr', i)]);
    }
```